# The meaning of |>! (forward pipe bang)

Tags: f#, piping, websharper

While perusing the Websharper online examples, I've come across examples like this:

```
Div [Attr.Style "padding: 5px;"] -< [
    P [Text "Type a name in the input field below:"]
    Form [
        label "First Name: "
        input
        |>! OnKeyUp (fun _ _ -> update ())
    ]
    P [
        label "Suggestions: "
        hint
    ]
]
```

We don't appear to be in a computation expression, and for some reason it's not particularly easy to Google the meaning of `|>!`.

What effect does the `!` modifier have in this context?  How does it change the outcome of the forward pipe?

Comment: Just FYI, the Stack Exchange search works for this sort of thing - just enclose the symbol in double-quotes. (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%7C%3E%22+%5Bf%23%5D )

Answer (score 2):

Mystery solved.  It's not a native F# operator; it's a Websharper operator.

From the source code (https://github.com/intellifactory/websharper/blob/master/src/stdlib/WebSharper.Main/Pervasives.fs#L105):

```
/// Implements piping with mutation.
[<Inline "($f($x), $x)">]
let ( |>! ) x f = f x; x
```

Comment: I just found it too :-) it is explained here: http://www.websharper.com/docs/pagelets